# Using Git for Collaboration

Tags: git, github

This is my first attempt at using Github's `shared collaboration model` to work on a project with a friend. I have started a project and added him as a collaborator. After commiting changes how can he update the repo on his computer and likewise how can I keep the repo updated? What if there are collisions and how are they resolved. I'll be grateful if someone could highlight some best practices or point to some resource.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to read http://help.github.com/remotes/

To answer some of your questions:
To update his repo, your friend would run git fetch, and afterwards git merge. git will then either merge the files directly, if there are no conflicts or ask him to resolve the conflicts manually, if the conflicts can't be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The best source of git knowledge is http://git-scm.com/book

**EDIT:**
The most important sections for you:

- 2.1 Getting Git repository
- 2.2 Recording Changes to the Repository
- 2.5 Working with Remotes
- 3.1 What a Branch Is
- 3.2 Basic Branching and Merging
- 3.5 Remote Branches

Comment: Do I need to read all of it? I'm a bit impatient to start working on the project. Any particular section I can read to know more about collaboration? Thanks